# Post with xmlhttp ( ASP ) - error response: No input XML data

Tags: asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

Please look at following code:

```
<form id='myform' name='myform' action='http://www.xxx.xom' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<input type='input' name='xmlData' value='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<order_zip>23222</order_zip>
<shipping_id>15</shipping_id>
<products><product> <product_id>230</product_id> <quantity>40</quantity></product></products>'>
</form>
```

when i send the form data - i got response as: **OK**.

However i need to do it in the backend (background).

So my code is:

```
set xmlhttp = server.createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST",URL,False
xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type","text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
xmlhttp.Send xmlstring
Response.write(xmlhttp.response.text)
```

This time i'm getting error response: **No input XML data**
The tech guy know only php no asp - so he does not know what i need to change in my code.

Here is the php code sample:

```
<?php
  $xml['xmlData'] .= '<order_zip>187654</order_zip>';
  $xml['xmlData'] .= '<shipping_id>3</shipping_id>';
  $xml['xmlData'] .= '<products>';
  $xml['xmlData'] .= '<product><product_id>458</product_id><quantity>11</quantity></product>';

  $connection = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.xml.com/xml/sendOrder");
  curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
  curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  set_time_limit(108000);
  $strResponse = curl_exec($connection);
  if(curl_errno($connection)) {
  print 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($connection);
  }
  curl_close($connection);
  print_r($strResponse);
  }
  ?>
```

I just need the form to run in background/backend - so i will be happy to get the right code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
xmlstring = "<root>" & _
            "  <order_zip>23222</order_zip>" & _
            "  <shipping_id>15</shipping_id>" & _
            "  <products>" & _
            "    <product>" & _
            "      <product_id>230</product_id>" & _
            "      <quantity>40</quantity>" & _
            "    </product>" & _
            "  </products>" & _
            "</root>"

set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST", URL, False
xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.Send xmlstring
Response.write xmlhttp.responseText
```

I added a root element to the XML otherwise it wouldn't be a valid XML-document.

See also this KB-article about the same subject: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290591